# What does chain foundation means in parity? What's the difference between mainnet and foundation?

Tags: parity

the `parity --help` has description below:

```
--chain=[CHAIN]
        Specify the blockchain type. CHAIN may be either a JSON chain specification file or
        olympic, frontier, homestead, mainnet, morden, ropsten, classic, expanse, musicoin,
        ellaism, testnet, kovan or dev. (default: foundation)
```

I really can't find what foundation means. And it seems having no difference with mainnet if you check the block on etherscan. So, dose anyone knows what's the difference between "foundation" and "mainnet" ? Branch of thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm, from the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/1cd93e4cebeeb7b14e02b4e82bc0d4f73ed713d9/parity/params.rs#L57), all of `foundation`, `frontier`, `homestead` and `mainnet` map to the same chain.

```
fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
    let spec = match s {
-->     "foundation" | "frontier" | "homestead" | "mainnet" => SpecType::Foundation,
        "frontier-dogmatic" | "homestead-dogmatic" | "classic" => SpecType::Classic,
        "morden" | "classic-testnet" => SpecType::Morden,
        "ropsten" => SpecType::Ropsten,
        "kovan" | "testnet" => SpecType::Kovan,
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really was worrying that if there is some differences. I should have checked the code.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation chain is the chain which is being supported by ethereum foundation and it is also referred to as mainnet.

Comment: thank you. But why it has both mainnet and foundation in the description?